# Good way of remembering Green's Theorem

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I am referring to Green's Theorem as follows: $$\int_C P\,dx+Q\,dy=\int\int_R (Q_x-P_y)\,dA.$$

Is there a way to remember it more easily, preferably by a intuitive way?

The problem is that I can remember the "form" easily enough (by seeing that it is an analogue of the fundamental theorem of Calculus for double integrals), but I may memorize it wrongly as:

$$\int P\, dx+Q\,dy=\int\int_R (P_x+Q_y)\,dA$$ for instance.

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: You need to remember how to differentiate a differential form. In this case $d(Pdx+Qdy)=P_y dy\wedge dx+Q_x dx \wedge dy=(Q_x-P_y)dx\wedge dy$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The integral on the surface is nothing but the integral of the $z$-component of the curl!

$$
E\equiv (P,Q,0)\implies (\nabla\times E)_z=\partial_x Q-\partial_yP.
$$

So, if you remember Stokes' theorem
$$
\oint_{\gamma}E\cdot dl = \int_{\Sigma} \nabla \times E \cdot dS
$$
for a curve $\gamma$ and a surface $\Sigma$ such that $\gamma = \partial \Sigma$, you are done. Indeed, only the $z$-component of the curl matters if the path $\gamma$ lies on the $xy$ plane, since then the surface area element has unit normal pointing in the $z$-direction.